# Modify Array of object dimensi with single object

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, key

i have state hardcoded for my menu sidebar like this, how can i update value with same key from another API, all i want just update the value with same key ?

```
   this.state = {
  navList: [
    {
      name: 'Data Analytics', 
      child: []
    },
    {
      name: 'Nelayan', 
      child: []
    },
    {
      name: 'Transaksi', 
      child: [
        { 
          total:0
        },
        { 
          totalDeposit:0
        },
        { 
          InputDp:0
        },

        { 
          totalCollections:0
        },
        { 
          totalProductions:0
        },
        { 
          totalShippings:0
        },
        { 
          totalShippingsDelivered:0
        },
        { 
          InputPayment:0
        }
      ]
    }
  ], 
}
```

So this is my API for count all transaction each menu above

```
 "data": {
        "totalDeposit": 0,
        "InputDp": 0,
        "totalCollections": 1,
        "totalProductions": 0,
        "totalShippings": 0,
        "totalShippingsDelivered": 0,
        "InputPayment": 12,
        "Supplier": 0,
        "Buyer": 0
    },
```

HOw can i update value with same key in react js ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reach that this way:

```
let navList = this.state.navList;
navList.map(item => {
  if (item.name === 'Nelayan') {
    item.child = // the data you want in array
  }
  return item;
});
this.setState({ navList })
```

First, make a copy.
Then, you should go over each item in array and compare with the data you want to change, for example the item called 'Nelayan', and then update the content and return it to the array. 
And last set the new state with the new array.

Note: You need an unique identifier to do that and be sure you are updating just the item you wanna do it for.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      personas: [
        { id: 1, nombre: "Adolfo" },
        { id: 2, nombre: "Juan" }
      ]
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("componentDidMount")
    let personas = this.state.personas
    personas.forEach(item => {
      if (item.id === 2) item.nombre = "Jose"
      return item
    })
    this.setState({ personas })
  }


  render() {
    console.log(this.state.personas)
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to React</h1>
        </header>
        <div className="App-intro">
          { 
            this.state.personas 
            ? this.state.personas.map((item, index) => {
              return <p key={index}>
                {this.state.personas[index].id} - {this.state.personas[index].nombre}
              </p>         
            })
            : ''
          }
        </div>
        {this.state.info ? this.state.info : 'No tengo info'}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: can you tell me more ?

Comment: What do you mean with more? To explain how it works?

Comment: wait, will try it lah, i let you know as soon as possible

Comment: Updated with a little explanation

Comment: shoudl it  item.child.totalDeposit = VALUE FROM API

Comment: If you wanna change just totalDeposit, then you need for example use spread operator ... in order to keep the other properties in it.. 
`this.setState({ navList: { ...this.state.navList, child: { ...this.state.navList.child, totalDeposit: X //the value } } })`

Comment: doesn't work, i have been see console.log doesn't change the value

Comment: What's the problem ? maybe you should share the rest of your code. Updated the answer with a full working example

Comment: so i tested hardcode doeesn't show u  item.child.totalDeposit = '10'

Comment: Yes, my fault. It should be...
this.state.navList[index].child..
So in map or forEach function you should add and index for that...
array.map((item,index) => { ... }